# Python print adds new line and 0

Tags: python, printing

Here's my issue. I'm trying to ssh to Cisco devices and pull information off. When I run my code, the print statement adds a new line with a 0 in it to the bottom of the output. Here is the output of the code followed by the output of the plink CLI input:

```
C:\Python30>python PLINKSSHtest.py
Enter your username: josh
Password:
plink -pw nowayjose -ssh nope@1.1.1.1 "show run | inc hostname"
hostname net-R2
0  <------------MY ISSUE

C:\Python30>plink -pw nowayjose -ssh nope@1.1.1.1 "show run | inc hostname"
hostname net-R2
  <------------WHAT I EXPECT
```

Here is my code:

```
def read_dev():
    # Print statement here for debugging
    print ("plink -pw " + password + " -ssh " + user + "@" + HOST + " " + command)
    cur_dev = os.system("plink -pw " + password + " -ssh " + user + "@" + HOST + " " + command)
    return(cur_dev)

HOST = None
user = input("Enter your username: ")
password = getpass.getpass()
command = '"show run | inc hostname"'
HOST = '1.1.1.1'    
print (read_dev())
```

Comment: Don't use Python 3.0, it was just a "proof of concept". Get the latest release of Python 3.1.

Comment: Short answer: You're printing the value returned by the `read_dev()` function. Remove the `print()` function call and invoke it by itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cur_dev` is getting the result code returned by the `plink` command, which is `0`.  Your `read_dev` function returns this code, so `print(read_dev())` prints the 0.

Just say `read_dev()` instead of `print(read_dev())`.

Comment: yep, thanks! I moved the print statemnt to inside the function and its all good now.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't "print zero". It prints `cur_dev` which is returned by `read_dev` function, which happens to be zero. And it does so, because you told it to. Remove `print` function and it won't print anything."

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explicitly set the exit code use `sys.exit(cur_dev)`. Simply using a return value from a function does not do what you want it to.